# How to use ports inside StartApp in Elm

Tags: elm

In my app that based on the StartApp package I have a port to communicate from inside the to JS. At the moment I call this port using a mailbox

```
requestPalette :
  { address : Signal.Address String
  , signal : Signal String
  }
requestPalette = Signal.mailbox ""


requestPaletteFilter : Signal String
requestPaletteFilter =
  Signal.filter (String.isEmpty >> not) "" requestPalette.signal
  |> settledAfter (300 * Time.millisecond)


port request : Signal String
port request = requestPaletteFilter
```

and using it like this:

```
[on "input" targetValue (\str -> Signal.message requestPalette.address str)
```

I wonder if there is a way to this inside of the `update` function instead of sending the message from the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This applies to elm 0.16 (and before), in elm 0.17 subscriptions have changed into ports*

In order to send a signal to a mailbox from an update, you'll need to use `StartApp` as opposed to `StartApp.Simple`, since the former allows for Effects in the `update` function.

At a bare minimum, you're going to probably have an Action like this, which defines a No-Op and an action for sending the string request:

```elm
type Action
  = NoOp
  | SendRequest String
```

Your `update` function will now include something like the following case for the new SendRequest action. Since you're using StartApp, which deals in Effects, you must call `Effects.task`, and the Task you're mapping to an Effect must be of type Action, which is why we have the `Task.succeed NoOp` return value.

```elm
update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp ->
      (model, Effects.none)
    SendRequest str ->
      let
        sendTask =
          Signal.send requestPalette.address str
            `Task.andThen` (\_ -> Task.succeed NoOp)
      in
        (model, sendTask |> Effects.task)
```

Now your click event handler in the view can go back to using the `address` passed into the view:

```elm
  [ on "input" targetValue (Signal.message address << SendRequest) ]
```

I've got a working example of the above in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/32e2d271afc1b5f6879d). You'll just need to subscribe to the `request` port in javascript to see it in action.

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear but I want comuncat from Elm to JS not the other way around

Comment: Thanks but this is still not an answer to the question, I have no problem to send the message, the question is about how to send it from the `update` function, so that the view only send message to the main address and every other communication is done in the central  place.

Comment: In that case, I think I understand what you're getting at now, but could you please update your question with an example (perhaps simplified) of what your StartApp code looks like, with the update function included?

Comment: Ok, @AndreasKöberle, I've updated the answer one last time. I'm pretty sure this is what you were after in the first place. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: This answer is for elm-0.16. For elm-0.17 look here https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html